# Interpolated DEM RMSE

Tags: dem, interpolation, modelling

I'm trying to figure out the 'true' error associated with interpolated cells in a DEM, which itself is known to have a RMSE of 0.15m.

1. DEM has RMSE of 0.15
2. Interpolation model shown by cross-validation to have an RMSE of 0.1

What is the RMSE of any interpolated cells?

Is it:

`0.15 + 0.1` or
`0.15 * 0.1` or even,
[image: rmse]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard the last of my suggestions was correct based on this extract from the following guidance.

[image: Error propagation]

See: [enter link description here](http://ipl.physics.harvard.edu/wp-uploads/2013/03/PS3_Error_Propagation_sp13.pdf)